# Somewhat Variadic function in Modern Fortran

Tags: fortran, variadic-functions, fortran95

I want to implement a logger functionality in some large Fortran code.
To do so, I want to provide the users with a simple 1-line function call, lets say `log_info(<list of variables>)` that accepts an unknown amount of variables from different types and ranks (variadic function).
This function will basically do what `write(*,*)` does, but on a buffer variable that i will manipulate for "pretty print" afterwards: `write(log_buffer,*) <list of variables>`.
Is this possible in Fortran? Because I know Fortran doesn't allow variadic functions, but this is a special case that i want to use the exact functionality of `write(*,*)` but creating a function that wraps it in order to hide it from the user.

You can imagine a code like this:

```
function log_info(<list of variables>) result(msg)

character(len=123456789) :: msg
write(msg,*) <list of variables>)

end function 



!!!!!!!!! the user code

log_info('what a great day', 12)
log_info('I wish fortran had variadic')
```

My friend though of a annoying workaround to run a C++ preprocesser with a variadic #define, and afterward to compile the result.

We have implemented the workaround but it doesn't work with CMake as it requires to execute C preproessor and compiling the result of the preprocessor

Comment: You don't need to explicitely run the C preprocessor, it it implicitly called by all Fortran compilers that I know if the file extension if `*.F90` (capital F).

Comment: Unless you are using an outdated compiler, you should remove the `fortran95` tag, as Fortran 95 has been obsoletized 20 years ago.

Comment: To explicitly say: something being possible in a statement or intrinsic procedure does not mean that the functionality of that something can be replicated in a user-defined procedure. You are aware that variadic functions don't exist, so perhaps you can give details of the nature of "pretty printing" and maybe get suggestions

Comment: For writing in particular, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19906446/3157076) covers some of the ground.

Comment: What might be useful for your case is to make generic subroutines with  unlimited polymorphic arguments distinguished by different number of arguments. There are limits of what you can do, of course.

Comment: I'm wondering, @VladimirFГероямслава, why that might be helpful. Polymorphic items must be processed by defined output, which is a lot of work and unusable for intrinsic dynamic type, meaning type guards. Helpful?

Comment: @francescalus Yes, I meant that for intrinsic types with typeguards.